# Using jQuery to find if a string value "Red" is in classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have multiples classes call "location" and I need to find if "Red" is in one of the class can I do that in jQuery?

```
<td title="Location" id="location_1" class="location" colspan="5">Red</td>
<td title="Location" id="location_2" class="location" colspan="5">Yellow</td>
.
.
.
<td title="Location" id="location_10" class="location" colspan="5">Orange</td>
```

I tried the following but is not working.

```
if($(".location").find("Red")){
    alert("found!");
}
```

What is the proper way to do it...if it is possible. Many Thanks!

Comment: Class, or value of the TD? You say class but it looks like you want the value of the TD given your "red" example.

Comment: I think he means "in one of the members of the class".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can

```
var reds = $(".location").filter(function(){
    return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'Red'
})

if(reds.length){
   alert('found')
}
```

Comment: **+1** no doubt this is better solution `;)`

Answer (score 5):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/487pg/1/)**

Try this:

```
if ($(".location:contains(Red)").length !== 0) {
    alert('found');
}
```

---

References:

- [`:contains()` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) - jQuery API Documentation

---

If you have the color name in a variable:

```
var color = 'Red';
if ($(".location:contains(" + color + ")").length !== 0) {
    alert('found');
}
```

- See [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/487pg/2/).

Comment: Will fail in case of a color which has a char sequence red

Comment: @user1934737 Did you get any errors? See [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/487pg/1/).

Comment: My mistake. Seems good. If I want to assign variable var red="Red" then how do I use ==> ($(".location:contains(Red)").length !== 0)?

Comment: @user1934737 You must use `$(".location:contains(" + red + ")")`. See my updated answer and [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/487pg/2/).

Answer (score 0):

The argument to `.find()` is a selector, not a text string to search for.

```
if ($(".location:contains(Red)").length > 0) {
    alert("found!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, based on the assumption you want to *do* something if it's found, rather than just read a number of alerts:

```
$('.location').filter(function(){
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText).indexOf('Red') > -1;
}).addClass('redFound');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3PtHG/).

The above allows you to style the elements in which the string 'Red' was found (`indexOf()` returns `-1` if a string is *not* found).

If you'd prefer the search to be case-insensitive, though you could simply use a regular expression, with `.test()`:

```
$('.location').filter(function(){
    return /\bred\b/gi.test(this.textContent || this.innerText);
}).addClass('redFound');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3PtHG/2).

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).
- [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Ftest).

Answer (score 0):

You should try to find their text() (this maps to "InnerText" in javascript):

```
      $("td").each(function()
{
   if($(this).text()=="Red")
   {
     //Do what you want
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$('.location').each(function(){  
     var my_cnt = 0;
     if ($(this).text() == "Red") {
           my_cnt += 1;
     } 
     if (my_cnt > 0) {
         alert("Match Found at "+my_cnt+" times");
     } else {
         alert("Match Not Found");
     }   
});
```